# Tag for ionospheric/propagation conditions?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, tags, tag-synonyms

I asked [this](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/94/are-ionospheric-predictions-useful-in-practice-for-ham-operators) question which I tagged 'ionosphere' (which didn't previously exist). User Mike added the tag propagation, which has one other question tagged. As far as HF goes, these tags are probably synonymous, but ionosphere is a more abstract way of describing the concept (so probably less useful).

Is there any reason why an ionosphere (or similar) tag might be needed, separate from propagation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's okay to have both a general tag and a more specific tag - for instance, your question tagged [ionosphere](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ionosphere) [propagation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation) is different from, say, someone asking about transmitting between rooms of their house, which might just be tagged [propagation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation).

Having the more specific tag allows people who care just about the more specific topic to refine their searches, while having the general tag allows those who are interested in the more general space to see everything in it.

Comment: It also opens up the possibility for both discussions relating to the ionosphere without being directly related to propagation ("what is the impact of the ionosphere on upper UHF range signals?") as well as non-ionospheric propagation. There isn't one yet, but I think we should anticipate a `line-of-sight` tag too.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer "the ionosphere fairy", but that is not in common use.